# BeautifulSoup - check for attribute / if no attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a function that scrapes information from a list of input URL's.

```
def scraper(inputlist):
    for url in inputlist:
        fullurl = baseurl + url
        hotelresponse = requests.get(fullurl)
        hotelsoup = BeautifulSoup(hotelresponse.text, "lxml")
        hoteltitle = hotelsoup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'vcard'})
        hotelhighprice = hotelsoup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pricing'}).text
        for H1 in hoteltitle:
            hotelName = hoteltitle.find('h1').text
            time.sleep(2)
    return (hotelName, hotelhighprice, fullurl)
```

In this particular case, "hotelhighprice" may not always have a value.

I want to

A) If hotelhighprice is there / has a value, I want to return it.
   If not, then print a string "empty".

then, to iterate on that

B) If hotelhighprice is not there, look for a different value (that I will specify as a variable.

Current error message -

```
  File "main.py", line 35, in scraper
    hotelhighprice = hotelsoup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pricing'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
text_value = getattr(hotelsoup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pricing'}), "text", my_default_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

A common code pattern is to check if what `find()` returns is "truthy":

```
price_elm = hotelsoup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pricing'})
hotelhighprice = price_elm.get_text() if price_elm else "Empty"
```

Or, in an expanded form:

```
price_elm = hotelsoup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pricing'})
if price_elm:
    hotelhighprice = price_elm.get_text() 
else: 
   hotelhighprice = "Empty"
   # or you may find a different element here
   # hotelhighprice = hotelsoup.find('div', class_="someotherclass").get_text()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = hotelsoup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pricing'}) 
if a is None:
  # no pricing
else:
  price = a.text
```